# A reference to a Blueprint Game Mode

Tags: c++, unreal-4

I am new to Unreal Engine with a very basic knowledge of working with the blueprints and code together. I am having trouble with making a reference of my Blueprint Game Mode in the code.

The question is that I have a Game Mode Blueprint (BP_GameMode) and I need to make a reference of it in a class Flag something like this:

```
BP_GameMode* TheGameMode = Cast<BP_GameMode>(GetWorld()->GetAuthGameMode());
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Also, can I execute a custom event in my BP_GameMode like this?

```
TheGameMode->IncreamentScore(Amount);
```